# Javascript variable scope behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

in my code below I don't understand why in the final console.log variable bearer_token is undefined if I've inizializated it within function __call.

```
home: function () {
  var bearer_token;
  var cb = new Codebird;
  cb.setConsumerKey("Zox*O8n1u", "zaCTe5oI23bxx***CG87e8hkgZgBeIHV7LKp");
  cb.__call(
    "oauth2_token", {},
    function (reply) {
      var bearer_token = reply.access_token;
    }
  );
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=felpone",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "myFunction",
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + bearer_token);
    }
  });

  function myFunction(r) {
    console.log(r);
  }
  console.log(bearer_token);
},
```

Comment: Remove the `var` from `bearer_token` inside the `function (reply)`. Each JavaScript function introduces a new scope.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Variable Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities:

```
function (reply) {
  var bearer_token = reply.access_token;
}
```

This piece of code assigns `reply.access_token` to a `bearer_token` *inside that function* and not the one outside the function. This means that if that code runs, it doesn't affect the outside `bearer_token`. To do so, remove `var`.

Next, I notice that function has an "oauth2_token" string. Is `__call` an asynchronous call? If so, then that function next to it is the callback. By the time you did `console.log(bearer_token)`, the response might have not yet arrived. To execute code after an asynchronous operation's response returns, place all the code that should run after the response arrives inside the callback.

This should work:

```
home: function () {

  var cb = new Codebird;
  cb.setConsumerKey("Zox*O8n1u", "zaCTe5oI23bxx***CG87e8hkgZgBeIHV7LKp");

  cb.__call("oauth2_token", {}, function (reply) {

    var bearer_token = reply.access_token;
    console.log(bearer_token);

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=felpone",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + bearer_token);
      }
    }).done(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });

  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a new variable bearer_token  in __call scope. Remove var.

Comment: I've removed var into __call but it is always undefined

Comment: Ensure that your function in __call is invoked before your AJAX call.